# understanding simple bootloader in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader

```
[org 0 x7c00]

mov bx , the_secret_three
add bx , 0x7c00
mov al , [bx]
int 0x10

jmp $

the_secret_three:
db "G"

times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

So the first line

```
[org 0 x7c00]
```

is there to tell the assembler where in memory the code should be placed, thereby avoiding overwriting any code that is already in the memory

now `mov bx , the_secret_three`

Why is this moved to bx? why not ax? and why is then later [bx] moved to al and not some other register?

What exactly does the label do? I read that it makes referencing the varible easier or something but didnt quite get it

Thanks for some clarification!!

Comment: That first line should be `[org 0x7c00]`, without the space.

Comment: This code is deeply flawed (beyond the issue microvirus mentioned). I would generally try to answer this, but I'm unsure you'd understand. Among the other bugs, you don't have a grasp of register indirect addressing and calling BIOS interrupts (_int 10h_). I'm going to offer up some advice, please talk to your instructor or teacher assistant. If you aren't taking up a formal class then I'd start by finding a beginners online tutorial about 8086/8088

Comment: If you want someone to actually try answering this I suggest you amend your question to state what it is you want this bootloader routine to do (it isn't actually clear from the code what the intent is). Do you want it to print the letter 'G' on the screen?

Comment: I can answer one part of your question. When writing a bootloader the BIOS will always load the first 512bytes (boot record) off the disk, and load it into memory at physical address 0x00007c00. After bootup, usually the memory between 0x00000600 and 0x00007c00 is free along with the memory between  0x00007e00 and 0x00090000 (you should set up your own stack manually).